# Can I use a format string in a URL to navigate to web page, replacing the specified portion of the URL?

Tags: c#, format-string, web-scripting

I'm interested in creating some sort of simple C# application takes a user string and passes it into a target portion of the URL. For example, since user query is visible  in the page URL DuckDuckGo

Example: 
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=web+browsers&ia=web

In this case, the URL shows that I searched for "web browsers". I would like the user to be able to pass any string to the application (via some kind of prompt that appears with the application is launched), and then launch a web browser and navigate to the target URL with the user input inserted into URL where the query is specified. (i.e., https://duckduckgo.com/?q=operating+systems&ia=web), where the user entered the string "operating systems".

So I would like to know which type of C# application to use that can interact with OS (Windows 10) and how to write the code for the the format String and the user prompt.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad so the best that can be done is give a broad answer.  You mention "application" and "interact with the OS", so I'm assuming a native application, not a web app.  A quick way to pull this off would be to Google for "C# Web Browser Example"; there are plenty of applications out there with well-explained source code that will answer your question:

> So I would like to know which type of C# application to use that can
>   interact with OS (Windows 10)

As for the string replacement, Armine already pointed that out in his previous post.  A simple textbox on your form, passed to some parsing code with string replacement, will do the trick for building the URL.  The resulting URL is then passed to the web browser control you've used in your C# application; the URL will be one of the properties of the control.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to take what user typed as a string, and then create another string which will contain the words of that string, separated by the plus character (+)

```
String what_user_typed=" javascript jquery";
String query=what_user_typed.Replace(" ","+"); // A space represents a new word
String url="https://www.google.com/search?query="+query
```

After creating the url you can then use a webbrowser to open that url

Answer (score 0):

I have not executed this but think this is what the logic should be.

```
string input = "operating system";
string destinationURL = $"https://duckduckgo.com/?q={input}&ia=web";
string formattedURL = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(destinationURL);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(formattedURL);
```